# Arduino http client not connecting

Tags: http, arduino, client

I have copied from several places portions of code and wrote this program that should connect to a server which I'm 100% sure is working, the IP address and the port are right, however `client.connect(server, 8000)` returns false, I'm new to networking so it's probably because of something basic

```
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte server[] = { 192, 168, 1, 100 };
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,127);

EthernetClient client;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  Serial.print("client is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

  if (client.connect(server, 8000)) {    //false returned here, of course then it doesn't work
    Serial.println("connected");
    client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.0");
    client.println();
  } else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}


void loop() {

  if (client.available()) {
      char c = client.read();
      Serial.print(c);
    }
    if (!client.connected()) {
      Serial.println();
      Serial.println("disconnecting.");
      client.stop();
      for(;;)
        ;
    }

  client.stop();
}
```

Comment: if you begin Ethernet with static IP address you don't know if it is really connected to network. try the WebClient example of the Ethernet library

Comment: @Juraj Thanks, it worked with dhcp, but in my project i'm going to need to identify a few boards uniquely and i prefer to not give them a string like "Arduino1" to transmit with all the data (they'll have to make a POST request but i'll manage this later), do you know how to make it work also with static ip adressing? I've alredy tried remove the dhcp configuration from the working sketch and just obtained the same error

Comment: try to specify all parameters for static IP configuration `void begin(const uint8_t* mac, IPAddress ip, IPAddress dns, IPAddress gateway, IPAddress subnet);`

Comment: Added 

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte server[] = { 192, 168, 1, 100 };
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,127);
IPAddress domainNameSystem(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);

and then Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, domainNameSystem, gateway, subnet);

but client.connect(server, 8000) still fails

Comment: firewall on server?

Comment: Did you replaced the dummy mac address with the actual address?

Comment: @Juraj no, and it any other browser from any other device can access it

Comment: @hcheung I red that the mac adress should be on a sticker on the shield but the one that was given to me doesn't have it, I tried to change a few times the mac adress and still got the same error

Comment: try the server IP as IPAddress.

Answer (score 0):

After making it work I forgot about having asked it here, but here's how I made it work, no idea of what was wrong before.

Of course be sure to turn off the firewall, so, for debian based systems:

> sudo ufw disable
>
> sudo ufw reload

Then I messed up with the code until I managed to do a POST request, I know I've asked for a GET, but the error mentioned in the question is now gone (I've notice the port changed, but that's because I've changed it on the server as well):

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

IPAddress server(192,168,1,100);

IPAddress ip(192,168,1,104);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress DNSServer(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, DNSServer, subnet);
  delay(5000);
  Serial.println("connecting..."); 
}

void loop()
{
   int correctValue;
   String PostData = "foo";
  
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    if (client.connect(server, 5000)) {
        Serial.println("connected");
        client.println("POST / HTTP/1.1");
        // Works either with or without any of the commented lines
        // guess it's a great idea to un-comment them though
        //client.println("Host: 192.168.1.100");
        //client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0");
        //client.println("Connection: close");
        client.print("Content-Length: ");
        client.println(PostData.length());
        client.println();
        client.println(PostData);
        client.println();
     }
     else {
       Serial.println("connection failed");
     }
     delay(10000);
  }
}
```

If you wanted to do a GET, it SHOULD be enough to change

> client.println("POST / HTTP/1.1");

with

> client.println("GET / HTTP/1.1");

then remove all the client.println(), the block with

```
if (client.available()) {
  char c = client.read();
  Serial.print(c);
}
```

should print it, since I'm not sure about it and can't confirm it I'll be more than happy to update the code if someone finds out the right way to do this